# renderer.setSize calculation by percent of screen? (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, three.js, screen

Are there any way to set renderer.setSize calculation by percent of screen?

For example i want my frame set 80% of device width and 80% of device height, can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get the device height using : `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`.

Then you apply your desired scaling factor when you set the size of the renderer like so :

```
   renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth * 0.8, window.innerHeight * 0.8);
```

Hope this help

Comment: @ThisIsSparta What you wrote was condescending. Period. You would be wise to understand the difference.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to update your canvas width and height during a resize of the window (like in css), you can use this code:

```
function resize() {
    var factor = 0.8; // percentage of the screen
    var w = window.innerWidth * factor;
    var h = window.innerHeight * factor;
    renderer.setSize(w, h);
    camera.aspect = w / h;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}; 

window.addEventListener("resize", resize);
```